# Looping req.body values with keys named key1, key2,

Tags: javascript, express, web

I'm working on my Express app, and I'm facing a problem: I want to create an array of objects, each having four properties taken from `req.body` (submitted through a form with `POST` method). Now, their names are progressive, e.g. image_1, image_2, image_3, and so on. How do I assign these values to the keys in a loop?

As you can see in the following code, I'm wondering how to assign the index value to the name of the value (the image is of course just an explanation of the problem, I can't do it with square brackets).

```
const submitted_form = req.body;
const submitted_cards = [];

for (let i = 0; i<3; i++) {
    submitted_cards[i] = {
        image: submitted_form.image_[i],
        title: submitted_form.title_[i],
        abstract: submitted_form.abstract_[i],
        link: submitted_form.link_[i],
    }
}
```

So, if I have for example `submitted_form` object:

```
{ image_1: 'mountains.jpeg',
  title_1: 'Mountains',
  abstract_1: 'some random text',
  link_1: 'www.google.com',
  image_2: 'jungle.jpeg',
  title_2: 'Jungle',
  abstract_2: 'some other random text',
  link_2: 'www.abc.com'
}
```

What I'd like to get from the loop is the following `submitted_cards` array:

```
[{ image: 'mountains.jpeg',
   title: 'Mountains',
   abstract: 'some random text',
   link: 'www.google.com'
},{
   image: 'jungle.jpeg',
   title: 'Jungle',
   abstract: 'some other random text',
   link: 'www.abc.com'
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let object =
{
  image_1: 'mountains.jpeg',
  title_1: 'Mountains',
  abstract_1: 'some random text',
  link_1: 'www.google.com',
  image_2: 'jungle.jpeg',
  title_2: 'Jungle',
  abstract_2: 'some other random text',
  link_2: 'www.abc.com'
}

var num_of_images = 2
var submitted_cards = []

for(let i=1; i<num_of_images+1; i++){
  let submitted_card = {
    image: object[`image_${i}`],
    title: object[`title_${i}`],
    abstract: object[`abstract_${i}`],
    link: object[`link_${i}`]
  }
  submitted_cards.push(submitted_card)
}

console.log(submitted_cards)
```

You should use pasala's answer's `${key}` to access the variables

Comment: Thank  you very much!   :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
submitted_form.image_[i]
```

to this

```
submitted_form[`${key}_${i}`]
```

where the key will be the prefix like image, title, etc.

Comment: Although this is correct, I find the syntax `submitted_form["key_" + i]` less confusing

Comment: Unfortunately both solutions don't work: submitted_form is an object, not an array, so to access its property I should use submitted_form.(something) instead of submitted_form[something], shouldn't I?

Comment: @DummyCamel, you should check the different ways to reference Object keys in JS. `obj[key]` and `obj.key` are both correct. `obj[key]` is generally used if key is a variable like in this case.

Comment: Thank you both guys! :)